# Seleccionar objetos asociados a listas relacionadas con LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Explico mi escenario.

1. Tengo un método que me devuelve una lista de objetos `Cuenta` (`Id_Cta`, `Desc_Cta`) en el método `GetCuentas(filtro)`
2. Tengo un método que me devuelve una lista de objetos `Usuario` (`Id_Usuario`, `CodUsuario`) en el método `GetUsuarios()`
3. Tengo un método que me devuelve una lista de objetos que relacionan cuentas con sus usuarios (`Id_Cta`, `Id_Usuario`) en el método `GetUsuariosCtas()`

Lo que necesito es con una sentencia LINQ obtener una lista de usuarios a partir de la lista de cuentas obtenidas con `GetCuentas(filtro)`

EDITO:
Las clases quedarían así:

```
public class Cuenta_poco { public int Id_Cta {get; set;} public string Desc_Cta  {get; set;} }

public class Usuario_poco { public int Id_Usuario {get; set;} public string Desc_Usuario  {get; set;} }

public class RelUsuarioCta_poco { public int Id_Cta {get; set;} public int Id_Usuario  {get; set;} }

public class Cuenta() { public List<Cuenta_poco> GetCuentas(filtro) {//Devuelve lista } }

public class Usuario() { public List<Usuario_poco> GetUsuarios() {//Devuelve lista } }

public class RelUsuarioCta() { public List<RelUsuarioCta_poco> GetRelaciones() {//Devuelve lista } }
```

Comment: Hola Carlos. ¿Puedes compartir el código que has intentado para solucionar el problema? Entre otras cosas, nos permitirá entender mejor cómo están definidos los objetos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He conseguido una solución. Partiendo de la base de que tenemos los objetos necesarios correctamente instanciados:

```
Cuenta cuenta = new Cuenta();
RelUsuarioCta usuarioCuenta = new RelUsuarioCta();
Usuario usuario = new Usuario();

var resultmp = usuariocuenta.GetRelaciones().Where(r => cuenta.GetCuentas(filtro).Any(c => c.Id_Cta == r.Id_Cta)).ToList();                 
var usuarios = usuario.GetUsuarios().Where(u => resultmp.Any(r => r.Id_Usuario == u.Id_Usuario)).ToList();
```

Mi intención era hacerlo en una única sentencia, pero si combino estas dos sentencias en una, el rendimiento baja dramáticamente.

También he probado haciéndolo en una única sentencia LINQ utilizando sub selects, pero el rendimiento también es horrible, tarda muchísimo en devolver los resultados en comparación con la solución que propongo.

Si alguien puede aportar una solución óptima que funcione con una sola sentencia, le agradecería.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

De la lista que devuelve el método `GetCuentas()` podrías obtener un listado de cuentas que cumplan alguna condición o cualquier propiedad del objeto `Cuenta_poco`  o algún tipo anónimo creado a partir de estas propiedades por ejemplo

var listafiltrada = lista_cuentas.Where(c => c.Id_Cta > 1);

var  consulta =from u in lista_cuentas where u.Id_Cta == 1 select u;

Para crear obtener una lista del tipo Usuario_poco  deberias hacer una consulta entre las secuencias devueltas por los métodos `GetCuentas` y `GetRelaciones`.

Nota el código que colocas tiene errores y no compila:

```
  using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;

    public class Cuenta_poco
    {
        public int Id_Cta { get; set; }
        public string Desc_Cta { get; set; }
        }

    public class Usuario_poco
    {
        public int Id_Usuario { get; set; }
        public string Desc_Usuario { get; set; }
    }

    public class RelUsuarioCta_poco
    {
        public int Id_Cta { get; set; }
        public int Id_Usuario { get; set; }
    }

    public class Cuenta
        {
        // Especificar el tipo del filtro . Se sugiere usar el delegado Predicate<T>
            public List<Cuenta_poco> GetCuentas()
            {
                return new List<Cuenta_poco>
             {
                 new Cuenta_poco{ Id_Cta = 1 , Desc_Cta="Descripcion cuenta 1 " },
                 new Cuenta_poco{ Id_Cta = 2 , Desc_Cta="Descripcion cuenta 2 " },
                 new Cuenta_poco{ Id_Cta = 3 , Desc_Cta="Descripcion cuenta 3 " },
             };
            }
        }

        public class Usuario
        {
            public List<Usuario_poco> GetUsuarios()
            {
                return new List<Usuario_poco>
             {
         new Usuario_poco{ Id_Usuario = 1 , Desc_Usuario= "Descripcion usurario 1 "},
         new Usuario_poco{ Id_Usuario = 2 , Desc_Usuario= "Descripcion usurario 2 " },
         new Usuario_poco{ Id_Usuario = 3 , Desc_Usuario= "Descripcion usurario 3 "},
            };
            }
        }

    public class RelUsuarioCta
    {
        public List<RelUsuarioCta_poco> GetRelaciones()
        {
            //Devuelve lista 

            return new List<RelUsuarioCta_poco>
         {
             new RelUsuarioCta_poco{ Id_Cta = 1 , Id_Usuario= 3 },
             new RelUsuarioCta_poco{ Id_Cta = 2 , Id_Usuario= 2 },
             new RelUsuarioCta_poco{ Id_Cta = 3 , Id_Usuario= 1 },
        };
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Cuenta cuenta = new Cuenta();
            // 1. Obtenemos los datos
            List<Cuenta_poco> lista_cuentas = cuenta.GetCuentas();
            // 2. Creamos la consulta usando metodos de extension
            IEnumerable<Cuenta_poco> listafiltrada = lista_cuentas.Where(c => c.Id_Cta > 1);
            // 3. Ejecutamos la consulta
            // Si solo requieres la lista deberias de llamar al metpdo .ToList() y cambiar el tipo de listafiltrada
            foreach (Cuenta_poco u in listafiltrada)
                Console.WriteLine($"Id_Cta :{u.Id_Cta}  Desc_Cta :{u.Desc_Cta}");


            //2. Creamos la consulta usando la sintansis de consulta    

    IEnumerable<Cuenta_poco> consulta =
              from u in lista_cuentas
              where u.Id_Cta == 1
              select u;

            // 3. Ejecutamos la consulta 
            // Si solo requieres la lista deberias de llamar al metpdo .ToList();
            foreach (Cuenta_poco u in consulta)
                Console.WriteLine($"Id_Cta :{u.Id_Cta}  Desc_Cta :{u.Desc_Cta}");
        }

    }
```